# Symbol.toPrimitive function call multiple time if function return undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, symbols

This is so interesting when I write code like bellow console show me first 1 after "string" 2 time.

```
Object.defineProperty(Date.prototype, Symbol.toPrimitive, {
    value: function (hint) {
        console.log(hint);
        return 1
    }
});


var date = new Date();
console.log(date);
```

Why "string" show 2 time and why "string" show after 1

Comment: I think this is engine's problem. Because I execute this code safari firstlt "string" show console before 1 but again "string" show multiple time :/

Comment: And maybe browser use also date function inside because that console show "string" multiple time :/

Comment: "*Why "string" show 2 time*" - apparently `console.log` is calling toPrimitive twice. There's nothing wrong with that. "*Why "string" show after 1*" - because `console.log(date)` is the first call to `console.log`

Comment: @Bergi 
Why console.log calling to call toPrimitive twice? What is mean there nothing wrong?))) 
And second one I wrote console.log(hint) first after return some value and this is mean first "string" must be show in console and safari work correctly and this is mean in there some problem

Comment: I don't know why it calls toPrimitive twice, and I don't care. It's just the way it is implemented. It's not something that needs to be improved, or something that doesn't comply with a standard - there is no specification. There is no problem.

Comment: I don't believe this is a real-world problem, logging to the console from a proxy trap comes up only in academic questions. (Please edit your question to show more of your use case and how the current behaviour does causes parts of your code to not work, if you want to persuade me). And of course you're free to file a bug against the Chrome Devtools if you think this needs to be improved, but I doubt you'll be heard. There's no reason (like a standard or something) that would suggest it had to work exactly the same as in Safari, that's just an unreasonable request.